# On call(chart), how to debug "Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Working on nvd3.js with a simple example ([line with view finder chart](http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav)). I can make it work when I use a basic single html page, but when I use it inside a custom angularjs  directive, it will fail on `call(chart)` with the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null` linking to d3.v3.js (line 759).

I can't spot a difference on code or variable values.
  Can you see where I'm doing wrong ? 
  What should I do to investigate further ?

Many thanks.

The working html: (which is a copy/paste inside a call to d3.json)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/nv.d3.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/nv.d3.css" type="text/css">    
 <link href="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
    <script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/nv.d3.js"></script>    
  </head>

<style>

body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}    
text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
} 
#chart svg {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;

}
</style>
<body>

  <div id="chart">
    <svg> </svg>
  </div>  

<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/utils.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/models/legend.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/models/axis.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/models/scatter.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/models/line.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/models/historicalBar.js"></script>
<script src="novus-nvd3-e2dd47b/src/models/linePlusBarWithFocusChart.js"></script>
<script>
var testdata = d3.json("myjson.json", function(error, myjson) {
       nv.addGraph(function() {
         var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

         chart.xAxis
             .tickFormat(d3.format('f'));

         chart.yAxis
             .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

         chart.y2Axis
             .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
         console.log('select:', d3.select('#chart svg'));
         d3.select('#chart svg')
             .datum(myjson)
           .transition().duration(500)
             .call(chart);

         nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

         return chart;
       });


});//end callback

</script>
```

This is my custom angular directive. The code fails on call(chart).

```
angular.module('app').directive 'lineChart',
['$log', ($log) ->
    restrict: 'AE'
    replace: true
    scope: { data: '=data' }
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        testdata = d3.json(scope.data, (error, json_data) ->
            nv.addGraph( () ->
                chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
                chart.xAxis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format('f'))

                chart.yAxis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'))

                chart.y2Axis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'))

                d3.select(element)
                    .datum(json_data)
                    .transition().duration(500)
                    .call(chart)

                nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update)
                return chart
                )
            )    

]
```

I call my directive from a `svg` html element in the template like this :

```
 div(ng-controller='metricsController')
     svg(line-chart, data='json_file')
```

Some values: d3.select(element) and element look like this :

```
select: 
[Array[1], select: function, selectAll: function, attr: function, classed: function, style: function…]
 lineChart.js:21
element: 
[svg.[object SVGAnimatedString], context: svg.[object SVGAnimatedString], jquery: "2.0.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
```

the exception is raised inside this function of d3.v3.js :

```
  d3_selectionPrototype.style = function(name, value, priority) {
    var n = arguments.length;
    if (n < 3) {
      if (typeof name !== "string") {
        if (n < 2) value = "";
        for (priority in name) this.each(d3_selection_style(priority, name[priority], value));
        return this;
      }
      if (n < 2) return d3_window.getComputedStyle(this.node(), null).getPropertyValue(name);
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null
      priority = "";
    }
    return this.each(d3_selection_style(name, value, priority));
  };
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add the chart to an `SVGAnimatedString` object. You need a group element or something like that.

Comment: Mmmh… I'll study that, but the selection `d3.select('#chart svg')` from the html is an `SVGAnimatedString` too.

Comment: Actually, the `select` structures where slightly different. The one used inside the directive had a JQuery object inside. That got me to the solution, which I'll explain in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it. The issue was due to the use of `element` inside the angular directive. As explained in my angular book:

"the `element` passed to the directive's `link` function is a wrapped reference to the native DOM element. […]_these are JQuery elements you're already used to work with. If you need direct access to the raw DOM element you can get it by accessing the first element of the object with `element[0]`."

So I had to use `element[0]`.